# Explanation for invariance of $c$ / Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, time-dilation, aether

First of all, I want to make it clear that I'm not proposing here that I have "discovered" something(I'm just trying to save myself here from accusations about being a relativity denier or some sort!). I am simply a programmer with some interest in physics, and am just hoping to bounce an idea I have had for some time to some more knowledgeable people.

So, I've been wondering what is the opinion here about providing an explanation for one of the principles of relativity, mainly the invariance of the speed of light in a vacuum.

It seems to me that SR works "backwards" - we start from the postulate(based on observation) that the (two-way) speed of light in vacuum is measured the same by all observers, then we work out the Lorentz transformations that would enable that to happen.

The thing is, unless I'm mistaken, there isn't an explanation of *why*, say, time dilates in such a fashion. We just accept that, in order for the postulate about the invariance of speed of light to hold, time(and other quantities) have to be transformed in such a way.

Now, bear with me and just imagine a simple "game-like" simulation. It would make it easier to just consider this simple game for now, and not worry if it has any correlation to the actual world. The rules are very simple:

- We have a background 3D space and time, and several instances of one type of particle that are moving in it.
- The particles exchange momentum using a mediator particle, that moves at a finite speed(we don't really care about its value). One particle emits a mediator, the mediator moves at a constant finite speed $C$, and after a while it gets absorbed by another particle. Simply put, C would be the speed of causality in this scenario.

Now my question is, *just* by considering this game and those rules, would a "player" inside this simulation experience something very close to, say, time dilation? It seems to me(and I have actually coded this "game" myself as a rough proof of concept), that a particle system (say a simple oscillator composed of 2 particles) that is travelling at speed V<C perpendicular to the oscillator, would vibrate slower than an identical system that is stationary, since the mediators would need more time in order to travel from the emitter to the absorber. An observer that is co-moving with this oscillator and uses it to measure the speed of light would actually measure C.

Now this isn't exactly my own idea - I have seen it asked before, though a bit differently, and I think Lorentz proposed something similar:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory

Now mind you, I'm not proposing that ether or an "absolute" frame is a useful physical notion, neither the distinction between "real" and "local" or "effective" time, and we always take it for granted that an observer can't determine their speed relative to this frame. The postulates of SR still absolutely hold.

My question is about the criticism that "we introduce ad-hoc hypotheses in order to explain why this absolute frame can't be detected". The notion that, if we assume momentum/energy can be exchanged at some finite speed, we will observe forces/time/length transforming in such a way doesn't seem "ad-hoc" to me. It seems a pretty simple way to explain time dilation to people without making it seem(to them) that something "magic" is happening "to time" when we move at great speeds, so how come this isn't used, at least for pedagogical reasons?

Anyway, I'd just like to hear some opinions about this. Does this explanation just break down somewhere and simply produces incorrect results?

Comment: You may be interested to know that the Lorentz transformations can be derived using only the homogeneity and isotropy of space (and an assumption about the equivalence of inertial reference frames) by studying a general transformation between reference frames. The resultant transformations have one free parameter which imposes a `speed limit' if it is finite. See for eg https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045v1

Comment: "The particles exchange momentum using a mediator particle, that moves at a finite speed" in what frame?

Comment: @Umaxo, good question. I suppose the whole simulation would be setup in such a way, that we just start by considering a background reference frame, and see if we get something similar to Lorentz transformation simply by assuming mediator particles move at a finite speed in that background frame.

Answer (score 2):

The modern view of special relativity is as a *geometric* theory, with time dilation and similar effects explained as a consequence of different observers having different directions in 4D spacetime as their preferred "axis of time". This geometric view of Minkowski spacetime leads naturally to general relativity. Trying to introduce a mechanistic "explanation" for SR would just obscure this and make the transition to GR that much more difficult.

In the geometric view the existence of an invariant speed $c$ is just a consequence of the way "distances" are measured in spacetime as $ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$; $c$ is the conversion factor between space and time, and usually we use units in which $c=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Now, the way I understand it, we *can* still start from this mechanistic explanation, simply to provide a more intuitive view of how the Lorentz transformations happen, and then derive the geometrical interpretation just the same, right? I'm not proposing a different formulation, but can't one say "well this is one way to think about it if it helps you, but the geometric formulation is very powerful so use that"?

Comment: I think the geometric view is more intuitive, and also more useful. Any mechanical explanation would have to be unlearned, and probably would lead to misunderstandings. As an analogy, two surveyors using different directions for north (one magnetic north, one celestial north) *could* try to come up with some mechanistic explanation for why their measurements differ. But any such explanation would ultimately not be helpful; the real reason they differ is that they chose to define "north" differently. Similarly, observers in relative motion define the directions of space & time differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of the oscillator moving along a line normal to its axis is an exception, and your game would not show the correct relativistic effect in other cases. In particular, if you had two identical oscillators, one moving relative to the background and one not, the one not moving would record time at a faster rate in an absolute sense, by which I mean that the 'stationary' oscillator would see the other time dilated, but not vice versa. The point about SR is that the mediator particle moves at a speed C relative to everything, and that the associated relativistic effects of time dilation, length contraction, no absolute simultaneity etc, are all entirely symmetrical between inertial reference frames. If you try to program your simulator to show other cases you will find that it will be unable to demonstrate those effects if it simply assumes the mediator particle moves at C relative to a fixed background. `You will also find that if the mediator particle moves at a fixed speed relative to the background, it will not move at a fixed speed relative to objects that are themselves moving relative to the background, which disagrees with all the experimental evidence about light.

To simulate all the observed effects of SR you would have to postulate a mediator particle that moves at the same speed relative to every other particle, which is exactly the same as saying that the speed of light is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. What you're saying though seems to disagree with what I'm reading about the Lorentzian ether - mainly that we *can* still assume an absolute reference frame, and all observers that are moving in reference to it undergo time dilation, length contraction, etc, in such a way that all of them(measuring "local time" and not "real time") measures the speed of light as C. From what I'm reading the predictions are identical to SR, including symmetry.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_theories_of_special_relativity#Robertson%E2%80%93Mansouri%E2%80%93Sexl_framework

Comment: Yes, that is all true. But the point is that the Lorenz ether theory makes more assumptions than your model of a particle that always moves at a fixed speed relative to some background, and it is more complicated than your simulation, and, in effect, it is mathematically the same as SR, so you don't gain anything by it.

Comment: Supposing that I light my torch at night and the duration that separates the two actions (lighting, extinction) is 1s . For an observer who is at rest at a distance of 1km from me, the duration is also 1s, but if he starts to move towards me at the same time as I light the torch, the duration of 1s will change, it will contract, in the opposite case , it will dilate as in the case where its initial speed is perpendicular to the axis of sight.
(the formulas of the Doppler effect remain valid)

Comment: If there is time dilation in the case where the observer approaches my torch, what physical time is it?

Comment: @The Tiler - Just to be clear, is this question addressed to me, or Marco?

Comment: For everyone, because I can't understand the physical meaning of time dilation in this case: an observer who approaches the ''epicenter'' of the events.

Comment: @TheTiler - Right, I think the key here is the assumption that speed of light for any observer is C - so even after they compensate for "traditional" signal delay, they will still observe time between events differently. I think people mention Einstein's "lightning that strikes 2 sides of moving train" thought experiment and leave that out - it's not that they will see light from the strikes at different times, people always knew that and there's nothing "relativistic" about it. It's that they will measure the speed of that light as C in all directions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%27s_thought_experiments#Trains,_embankments,_and_lightning_flashes

"The combination of Einstein's first and second postulates implies that, despite the rapid motion of the train relative to the embankment, M' measures exactly the same speed of light as does M. Since M' was equidistant from A and B when lightning struck, the fact that M' receives light from B before light from A means that to M', the bolts were not synchronous."

Speed of light measured as C by moving observer is the key here, otherwise it's just simple signal delay.

Comment: Even in this case of "interpretation", what time is it (Δt> Δτ)? The watch of the observer who approaches the epicenter of the events will indicate a Δt< Δτ .(by simple analogy with the sound waves ...., and we know that the mediator vector of information in our case is the light (photons ))

Comment: @The Tiler I could be wrong, but I think the observer would determine the time of "torch on" event the same way they would determine the time of a "sound on" event - time you detected the event, minus the time it took the signal to reach you.
What SR adds is that light speed relative to any observer is C, which isn't true in the case of sound(which differs for different observers), and that is what leads us to predict time dilation.

I think the way one gets the info is not relevant - as I said, the event could be "sound on" instead, and Lorentz transformations would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Explanation for invariance of c

There is a semi-explanation in Maxwell theory. Basically, this theory says that the interaction between charged particles travels at certain speed. Of course, speed is relative, so the natural question was to ask in what frame is this speed being measured. By picking any such frame you are basically admitting that there exists preferred frame of reference. If you want to keep all inertial frames of reference being equivalent to each other, you need to admit this speed is the same for all observers. So the invariance of c is kind of a consequence of principle of relativity and finite speed of interaction.

Historically, physicists tried to circumvent this by postulating that Electromagnetic field is carried by some substance and the speed is relative to this substance. In this case, the principle of relativity would be broken by coincidental distribution of the substance and not by physical laws themselves, just like principle of relativity is broken in the vicinity of Earth by Earth itself (E.g. there is preferred "downward" direction in the vicinity of Earth).

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are trying to do, so I agree that Lorentz proposed similar explanation.

Basically, from what I understand of Lorentz ether theory, the fact that Maxwell equations have different form in different frames of reference would have to be also applied on our watches and metersticks that also work on electromagnetic principle. Their mechanism would change in different frames of references - clocks would started to tick in different rates in different frames and meter sticks would stretch in different frames. When Lorentz computed this, he found out, that it is self cancelling effect. Your watches and metersticks are deformed in such a way that Maxwell equations will be invariant in all frames, even though they are not if you use the "correct" time and distances.

If you like this explanation more than the mainstream (geometric) one consider this - ether  explanation only works because Maxwell equations are Lorentz invariant. But why should they be Lorentz invariant? And why should other interactions (gravity, weak and strong force) be also Lorentz invariant (with the same constant "c")?

Ether theory does not explain this at all, but in mainstream STR Lorentz invariant interactions are natural.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. Your third paragraph from the end hits the nail completely.

Comment: Ofc my approach is extremely crude. It isn't meant to model the real world, not really, but-I do definitely see some analog to time dilation in my crude "game". If I showed you just the game and asked you "assuming you can only measure time and space using clocks and rods made by those virtual atoms, can you come up with some transformations between different frames of reference" - you *would* end up with something somehow similar to Lorentz transformations.We *would* know why we see this "invariance".

Do you see any issue with this?

Comment: @MichaelMitsopoulos The basic idea makes sense to me. However your game would have to lead to Lorentz invariant interaction. In EMF , the crucial component of Lorentz invariance is the way electric field transforms into magnetic field. If you want to make your game work, the mediator particles would have to carry the momentum in this special form.  I don't think the assumption "mediator particles move at a finite speed" from your previous comment would be enough.

Comment: @MichaelMitsopoulos but again, you are complicating the whole issue. The game could be interesting visualization, but you need to assume Lorentz invariance of the interaction beforehand. In geometric formulation, you assume Lorentz invariance of spacetime itself. The assumption is the same, the geometric one is just more general and explains all the interactions in one go.

Comment: If it is not clear, I am making reference to Eric Smith answer and the discussion below it.

Comment: that's what it's not clear to me - *do* I need to assume anything besides the game rules above? 

What I do see is that, *if* I model all interactions by having atoms emitting/absorbing mediators that move at C, any "moving virtual clock" I construct will by necessity exhibit some sort of retardation, simply because of the (classical) Doppler effect of the mediator pulses - atoms in a moving clock simply exchange energy in slower pace.

Of course, that's just my crude game - not SR. It's probably beyond my current skills to prove anything further(if that's possible).